# How I could run a scheduled task with powershell and schedule.service

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm using schtask for running a scheduled task in a Powershell 3 (Win7) :

```
$taskname = "task"
schtasks /Run /Tn $taskname
```

Now, I'm trying to do the same thing with Schedule.service :

```
$ProductName ="task"
$ScheduledTaskService=new-object -com("Schedule.Service") 
$ScheduledTaskService.connect() 
$ScheduledTaskToRun=$ScheduledTaskservice.GetFolder("\").GetTasks(0)|Where-Object{($_.Name -eq $ProductName)}
```

But at this point, I don't know what I need to do for running the task. This task is already configurated and need only to be launch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the task with the `.Run()` method passing a null:

```
$ScheduledTaskToRun.Run($null)
```

I haven't found the documentation reference yet, so I'm not sure what the parameter specifies, but I'll update the answer when I find it, or someone else is welcome to do it if they find it before I do.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382094(v=vs.85).aspx is the closest I've found, but it shows two parameters, and `.Run()` fails on my system when two parameters are passed because there is no Run() overload with two arguements.  So I don't know if this page is Windows 10?

Comment: Make sure to also consider using RunEx (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382095(v=vs.85).aspx), or alternatively, using the Powershell cmdlets. (PS> get-help New-ScheduledTask)

Comment: @TonyHinkle Bit late, but ... You're right that it lists 2 params, but if you notice closely the second one is marked as `ByRef out`. That's why you only pass one. So in short, it's got nothing to do with Win10, you should just pass 1 param.

Comment: @TonyHinkle also, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380767(v=vs.85).aspx